# Windows 10 Cannot remove kiosk mode: Error: Try your changes again

Tags: windows, windows-10, kiosk

I have just setup kiosk mode (Assigned Access) on my Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363. After playing around with it for a bit with the assigned app set to Clock I wanted to get rid of it again and went to the settings menu to remove it again. But whenever I try to click on "remove", it shows the loading indicator for a while and then errors out with: "Try making your changes again. Something went wrong." I have already tried to enable UAC on the highest level as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-troubleshoot) . But no success.

Thanks for your help in Advance,
Phillip.

Comment: I assume your User Name is a member of Administrators Group.  Try DISM and SFC.  Open an admin command prompt and run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW  .. Restart when done and test.  You may need to make or use another User Name and/or Safe Mode with Networking

Comment: Thanks! Sadly this did not fix the problem. I did dism and sfc and restarted - still did not work. I tried another user in combination with network safe mode- also no success. This seems to be a persistent issue

Comment: Then you now need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Follow the second link, run in place and at the appropriate spot Keep Everything. This should likely work. 

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: @John Maybe it's time to take the bull by the horns and post the preceding comment as an answer.

Comment: Good idea and I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Since the comments provided did not solve the problem, then you now need to do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link. Follow the second link, run in place and at the appropriate spot Keep Everything. This should likely work.

Here is the appropriate link for Windows Repair Install:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue, and running the suggested `DISM` and `SFC` commands didn't help either.

While it does not fix the issue per se, I created a BATCH script that removes the keys associated to the assigned access configuration.

It will effectively remove the kiosk mode.

```
@ECHO OFF

REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\AssignedAccessConfiguration
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR_KEYNOTFOUND

ECHO Deleting the key AssignedAccessConfiguration...
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\AssignedAccessConfiguration /F
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ERROR_NOTADMIN

ECHO Assigned access is deleted.
GOTO FINALLY

:ERROR_KEYNOTFOUND

ECHO Unable to find the key AssignedAccessConfiguration.
GOTO FINALLY

:ERROR_NOTADMIN

ECHO Launch this BATCH as administrator.
GOTO FINALLY

:FINALLY

PAUSE

@ECHO ON
```

Answer (score 0):

kagmole script worked. It removed the keys assigned for KioskMode. KioskMode automatically sets up a user account so I deleted that too.

Computer Management > Local users and Groups > User > then you will find the account that you created under Kiosk mode - just delete that.

Kiosk Mode Gone.